# How to optimize a Async Function

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am pretty new to python. I am trying to scrap through the data of an API. I have used youtube tutorials to make this code. This script takes 7 seconds to go through the whole API but I want to make it even faster so what optimizations can I do. I am running this script from another script as a module.

also how to remove those line as I don't need it

```
GetData = asyncio.ensure_future(getPageData(session, page))
PageData.append(GetData)
idkWhatHowToNotUseIt = await asyncio.gather(*PageData)
```

```
########## NOTE: Imports ##########

import requests
import asyncio
import aiohttp

########## NOTE: Variables ##########

results = []

########## NOTE: Functions ##########
async def getPageData(session, page):
    async with session.get(
            f'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?page={page}'
    ) as response:
        auctions = await response.json()
        for auction in auctions['auctions']:
            if 'bin' in auction:
                responseData = {
                    'uuid': auction['uuid'],
                    'auctioneer': auction['auctioneer'],
                    'item_name': auction['item_name'],
                    'starting_bid': auction['starting_bid']
                }
                results.append(responseData)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        PageData = []

        TotalPages = requests.get(
            'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?page=0').json()
        print(f'--> Total ' + str(TotalPages['totalAuctions']) +
              ' Auctions Found.')

        for page in range(0, TotalPages['totalPages']):
            GetData = asyncio.ensure_future(getPageData(session, page))
            PageData.append(GetData)

        idkWhatHowToNotUseIt = await asyncio.gather(*PageData)

        print(f'--> {len(results)} Auctions Finalized.')
        return results
```

Comment: Measure what part of code is taking too much time. If it's request/response time which is taking too much time, then either your network speed is slow or the response is quite big.

Comment: @kiner_shah Ok measured it is the request taking time so if we cant improve then ok but how to remove that part
GetData = asyncio.ensure_future(getPageData(session, page))
PageData.append(GetData)
idkWhatHowToNotUseIt = await asyncio.gather(*PageData)

Comment: What do you mean how to remove? Just delete those lines if you don't need or comment them.